# How resize of video in terminal?

Tags: command-line, video

I have video with size 560x288. I would like video with size 500x250 (change ratio and cut off rest).

How to in terminal, please?

Comment: Check out: https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/FilteringGuide. There isn't really a simple way to do this, but I suggest starting there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me this [link](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/FilteringGuide) from ***[DaboRoss](https://askubuntu.com/users/115738/daboross)***.

For example command for resize: `ffmpeg -i in.ogv -vf "crop=500:250:13:0" out.ogv`